# Update table using day name value - Oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

i'm new to this forum and oracle pl/sql. I have been doing some pl/sql task since last few days. One of the task is to update the amount value in revised amount column. I'm using cursor method for this task.

I need to update the value of revised amount column by +10(monday), +20(tuesday)..etc..

I'm facing issues updating the revised amount.

please check the codes below.

```
create or replace procedure team2
as 
  cursor c1 is select amount, day_name from football;
  v_amount football.amount%type;
  v_day football.day_name%type;
begin
  if c1%isopen then
    close c1;
  end if;

  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 into v_amount, v_day;
    exit when c1%notfound;

    if  v_day = 'monday' then
      update football set revised_amount = v_amount+10 where day_name = v_day ;
    elsif v_day = 'tuesday' then
      update football set revised_amount = amount+30 where day_name = v_day ;
    elsif v_day = 'wednesday' then
      update football set revised_amount = amount+40 where day_name = v_day ;
    elsif v_day = 'thursday' then
      update football set revised_amount = amount+50 where day_name = v_day ;
    elsif v_day = 'friday' then
      update football set revised_amount = amount+60 where day_name = v_day ;
    elsif v_day = 'saturday' then
      update football set revised_amount = amount+70 where day_name = v_day ;
     elsif v_day = 'sunday' then
       update football set revised_amount = amount+80 where day_name = v_day ;
     else
       dbms_output.put_line(' output failed');
     end if;
  end loop;
  close c1;
End;
/
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines in the Help Center on asking questions on this site. Also, please click the "Edit" button below your question and use the "code" button in the toolbar to format your code as a code block, then remove empty lines and INDENT it properly so that people can read it.

Comment: You haven't told us what issues you are having. Showing table structures and data is also usually useful. Presumably this is an assignment and you're intentionally doing this in a long-winded way, as it can be done simply without PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need a cursor:

```
create or replace procedure team2
as 
begin
  UPDATE Football
  SET    revised_amount = amount
                        + DECODE(
                            day_name,
                            'Monday',    10,
                            'Tuesday',   20,
                            'Wednesday', 30,
                            'Thursday',  40,
                            'Friday',    50,
                            'Saturday',  60,
                            'Sunday',    70
                          );
END;
/
```

(and you don't really need the procedure)

Comment: I can understand,but the task is to complete it using procedure/cursor. Thanks a lot a for your reply. would be greatly appreciated if you can help me with the output using cursor.

Comment: Thanks MTO for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

try the following approach:

```
update football
  set revised_amount = amount + case day_name when 'monday' then 10 when 'tuesday' then 20 ... when 'sunday' then 80 end
;
```

Only monday:

```
update football
  set revised_amount = amount + case day_name when 'monday' then 10 end
where day_name in ('monday')
;
```

Comment: Hi MaxU, thanks for the reply. could you explain/write the query for monday alone.so i will try to understand it.